# Parallel way of applying function element-wise to a Pytorch CUDA Tensor

Tags: gpu, torch, pytorch, tensor

Suppose I have a torch CUDA tensor and I want to apply some function like `sin()` but I have explicitly defined the function `F`. How can I use parallel computation to apply `F` in Pytorch.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the question?  Do you want a user-defined `F` to be executed in the GPU?

Answer (score 2):

I think currently, it is not possible to explicit parallelize a function on a CUDA-Tensor. A possible solution could be, you can define a Function like the for example the non-linear activation functions. So you can feed forward it through the Net and your function.

The drawback is, it probably don't work, because you have to define a CUDA-Function and have to recompile pytorch.

Comment: Thank you. Upon further exploration the solution for me was to use cuda libraries directly and programming the gpu kernel. I also feel it’s not possible in Pytorch or Tensorflow yet.

Comment: Unhappily, currently you have to implement it by your own.

Comment: @abhinav-singh Can you answer your own question to show how you did it? I would like to implement similar functionality.